# Excluding rows from dataframe which have atleast one zero value Ctrl or Mn named columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame with 6 Ctrl columns and 6 Mn columns. I need to exclude rows which have zero values for atleast one Ctrl and atleast one Mn Column seperately.

Unfiltered Data :

```
  Ctrl1 Ctrl2   Ctrl3 CtrlA CtrlB   CtrlC   Mn4 Mn5 Mn6 MnD MnE MnF
        SLC7A2  0   0.09    0   0.1 0.02    0   0   0   0.06    0   0   0
        CACNG3  1   2   1   2   0   3   0   1   2   3   0   0.06
        GGCT    1   0   2   3   5   4   3   1   4   1   3   1
        UPP2    1   2   0.06    3   4   4   5   6   7   8   6   3
        PRSS21  2   1   3   4   5   4   4   5   4   6   0   1
        PRR5    2   2   1   2   3   1   2   1   1   3   2   0
```

Filtered Data results :

```
          Ctrl1 Ctrl2   Ctrl3 CtrlA CtrlB   CtrlC   Mn4 Mn5 Mn6 MnD MnE MnF
            GGCT    1   0   2   3   5   4   3   1   4   1   3   1
            UPP2    1   2   0.06    3   4   4   5   6   7   8   6   3
            PRSS21  2   1   3   4   5   4   4   5   4   6   0   1
            PRR5    2   2   1   2   3   1   2   1   1   3   2   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way in base R using `apply` -

```
df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x[1:6] == 0) & any(x[7:12] == 0)), ]

       Ctrl1 Ctrl2 Ctrl3 CtrlA CtrlB CtrlC Mn4 Mn5 Mn6 MnD MnE MnF
GGCT       1     0  2.00     3     5     4   3   1   4   1   3   1
UPP2       1     2  0.06     3     4     4   5   6   7   8   6   3
PRSS21     2     1  3.00     4     5     4   4   5   4   6   0   1
PRR5       2     2  1.00     2     3     1   2   1   1   3   2   0
```

Using `rowSums` should be more efficient I think -

```
df[!((rowSums(df[1:6] == 0) > 0) & (rowSums(df[7:12] == 0) > 0)), ]
```

Data -

```
df <- structure(list(Ctrl1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Ctrl2 = c(0.09, 
2, 0, 2, 1, 2), Ctrl3 = c(0, 1, 2, 0.06, 3, 1), CtrlA = c(0.1, 
2, 3, 3, 4, 2), CtrlB = c(0.02, 0, 5, 4, 5, 3), CtrlC = c(0L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L), Mn4 = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L), Mn5 = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 1L), Mn6 = c(0.06, 2, 4, 7, 4, 1), MnD = c(0L, 
3L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 3L), MnE = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 2L), MnF = c(0, 
0.06, 1, 3, 1, 0)), .Names = c("Ctrl1", "Ctrl2", "Ctrl3", "CtrlA", 
"CtrlB", "CtrlC", "Mn4", "Mn5", "Mn6", "MnD", "MnE", "MnF"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("SLC7A2", 
"CACNG3", "GGCT", "UPP2", "PRSS21", "PRR5"))
```

Comment: I think you can simplify(?) the `rowSums` approach by `df[rowSums((df[1:6] == 0) & (df[7:12] == 0)) == 0, ]` It's the same thing though.